# Unauthorized on calling Dynamics 365 endpoint

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I am calling a Dynamics 365 endpoint to execute a query:

```
https://dev-xxx-ssp.api.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name
```

To do this, I am authenticating with this code:

```
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential("9cd8fe45-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e43ef81c803f", "abcdefghij");
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/our-domain.onmicrosoft.com");
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://dev-xxx-ssp.api.crm6.dynamics.com/", clientCredential).Result;
```

I then initialise the HttpClient:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://dev-xxx-ssp.api.crm6.dynamics.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
```

I can see after doing this that the HttpClient has an authorisation token, such as:

```
{Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IndVTG1ZZnNxZFF1V3RWXy1oeFZ0REpKWk00USIsImtpZCI6IndVTG1ZZnNxZFF1V3RWXy1oeFZ0REpKWk00USJ9.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.AN8CcEBluMJPBtpbqv4Q6V3dO75Y8whoBRw_Nk6u4RhbWAz1BRIIeIBNGBNneJ0Zlnfh-7_W_TH_jAiQNIJxmGhQLOTFKYxXvvq3ksS-efqdGZlwY0dU7LGM-nxDxVZhfnW18F2yBE0skRLMmB27RyCHbIkU6S5HKTfq8LEIvCaUILh00wSItTXFX1ew14T3_6yZ81x_A-d1cc_oPPbRssIlXmD8ybYVfCjc_v57TuyR1pLf2HnlK04w2ioB0KJ545BCD6nJyuC0iL_2YKdGuHxHIrbRZShu-SGihXmugRgBYl3kF-zCDiWlxAIz9F2WyMWylM1qfDnIUZrgDowxbQ}
```

I then execute a query:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://dev-xxx-ssp.api.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name");
request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=10");
request.Headers.Add("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue");
HttpResponseMessage response = this.Client.SendAsync(request).Result;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  // ...
} else {
  throw new Exception(String.Concat("Dynamics query returned unexpected status: ", response.StatusCode.ToString())
}
```

I get an Unauthorised StatusCode at this point, which I trap in my if branch and throw as an exception.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably logged in with the wrong user who doesn't have the access right. User info can be acquired and checked like this:

```
UserInfo user = authenticationResult.UserInfo;
```

Adding `PromptBehavior.Always` enum as a parameter to `AcquireToken()` method forces the sign-in dialog to prompt even if a token exists in the cache. So you can try other identities.

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult 
        = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, applicationId, new Uri(redirectUrl), PromptBehavior.Always);
```